# Class Based View MySQL DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am very new to Django and at the end of my rope and really need some help.

I do not know how to use a "class based view" and change the incoming datetimefield from my MySQL database into a Time Zone Supported entry that it seems to need.  The database stores it in UTC and my system is on PST.

I am getting this error:

DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2012-09-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active

On my MonthArchiveView, DayArchiveView, DateDetailView 's only.  For some reason my ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView class based views work ok.

Here is my model:

```
class blogpost(models.Model):
  blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  blog_slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='blog_pub_date', max_length=200)
  blog_content = models.TextField()
  blog_pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
  blog_category = models.ForeignKey('blogcategory')
```

Here is one of my Views:

```
class ThoughtsDetailView(DateDetailView):
  template_name='thoughts/thoughts_detail.html'
  queryset = blogpost.objects.all()
  date_field = 'blog_pub_date'
  slug_field = 'blog_slug'
  context_object_name = 'thoughts_detail'
  month_format = '%m'
  allow_future = 'true'
```

Here is an example template:

```
{% block content-inner-left %}
<h1>{{ thoughts_detail.blog_title }}</h1>
<div id="blogpost">
  <p class="blogsmalldate">[ Posted on {{ thoughts_detail.blog_pub_date|date:"l, F dS, Y" }}, {{ thoughts_detail.blog_pub_time|date:"g:i a" }} ]</p>
  <br />
  <p>{{ thoughts_detail.blog_content|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
</div>
{% endblock content-inner-left %}
```

Can someone help me understand how to fix my Day Detail View so that it stays as a Class Based View and then I can probably figure out the others.  I even tried to use PYTZ but don't understand enough how to change the class based view to use it.   Thank you....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the view, but in the fact that the dates are stored in the database without a timezone information, while Django is set up to support timezones. If you don't need timezone support, simply set `USE_TZ = False` in the settings.py; if you do, make sure that the database stores the dates with the timezone information. More details on that can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: I am sorry in that I should have stated that I know the problem is that MySQL isn't storing the dates with TZ data.  DateTimeField does not and I don't know how to get around this.  Everything in MySQL says this is not an option and I cannot use any other DB program.  So I need to make the data aware of TZ information after I pull it from the DB and then inject it into the view so that it shows the correct details and get rid of the error. Or I need another option on how to get around the error.

Comment: I see. Perhaps this answer could point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034823/django-converting-old-datetime-field-to-new-1-4-datetime-with-time-zone-aware-in

Comment: Thank you for that information but I have seen the template components and tried them and they didn't help much.  But this information does explain that I guess it already makes the DateTimeField aware once it pulls it form MySQL.  I still don't have an answer to solve my problem because the load tz, etc doesn't work with how the documents say.